# How access class functions with <future> library?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a program with `#include <future>` library.

When I try to access a header function, I get an error.

```
no instance of overloaded function "async" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::launch, int ()) [line 16, 14]

a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
[line 16, 37]
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "TEST.h"
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Class;

FNH f;


int main(){
    auto fn = async(launch::async, f.selam);
}
```

TEST.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace Class{

    class FNH{
        public:
        int selam(){
            cout << "selam";
            return 1;
        }
    };

}
```

I'm a beginner at coding so I really don't know how to fix it or if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a member function pointer and the instance of the class it will be called on:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

namespace Class {

class FNH {
public:
  int selam(){
    std::cout << "selam";
    return 1;
  }

  int selam_2(int a, int b){
    std::cout << "selam "<< a << " " << b;
    return 1;
  }
};

}

int main(){
  Class::FNH f;

  // Member Function Pointer
  auto fn = std::async(std::launch::async, &Class::FNH::selam, f);

  // Member Function Pointer with arguments
  auto fn2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Class::FNH::selam_2, f, 1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the method call in a lambda

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

namespace Class{

class FNH {
public:
  int selam(){
    std::cout << "selam";
    return 1;
  }
};

}

int main(){
  Class::FNH f;
  auto fn = std::async(std::launch::async, [&f]{ return f.selam(); });
}
```

Comment: Really thank you! I got this error for long while.